# Trouble making a sign operator appear on a text box

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the ADD div is clicked, "+" should appear on the textbox. Same goes for SUBSTRACT, MULTIPLY and DIVIDE. I cannot make the operators display on the textbox. This is what I have got so far.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <div class="leftDiv">
       <div id="colorblock">
        <div id = "add" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr()">ADD</div>
        <div id = "subtract" class = "blocks">SUBTRACT</div>
        <div id = "multiply" class = "blocks">MULTIPLY</div>
        <div id = "divide" class = "blocks">DIVIDE</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    <input type = "text" size="1" id = "operator">
    
    
    <script>
    function displayOptr() {
        var optrArr =["+","-","*","/"];
        for (var i = 0; i < optrArr.length; i++){
         if (i==0){
             document.getElementById("operator").value = "+";
            } else if (i==1){
             document.getElementById("operator").value = "-";
            } else if (i==2){
             document.getElementById("operator").value = "*";
            } else if (i==3){
             document.getElementById("operator").value = "/";    
        }
        
        
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And what problem are you having? What exactly is your question?

Comment: I cannot make the operators display on the textbox.

Comment: Are you getting an error in your console? Your current code has a syntax error - - you are missing the closing curly brace for your `if` statement.

Comment: Not that I know of. My apologies, I'm new to javascript.

Comment: While trying to run the code in  your browser, press F12 to open the developer tools panel. Then, click on the tab marked "Console". This is where your errors will appear. You will see that you currently have an error and it is because your `if` statement is missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using inline function calls - I posted an Answer which might help you in understanding the code better.

Comment: your function is not closed, so your test do not work. add `}` to close the function and see your test working. your test will always show the sign `/`which is the last one of the loop :)

Comment: your function is not closed, so your test do not work. add `}` to close the function and see your test working. your test will always show the sign `/`which is the last one of the loop :)  see your function fixed and a diiferent id for each loop http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZKYWQB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to display each symbol depending on which operation was selected, here is a working solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <div class="leftDiv">
       <div id="colorblock">
        <div id = "add" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr(this);">ADD</div>
        <div id = "subtract" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr(this);">SUBTRACT</div>
        <div id = "multiply" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr(this);">MULTIPLY</div>
        <div id = "divide" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr(this);">DIVIDE</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    <input type = "text" size="1" id = "operator">
    
    
    <script>
    function displayOptr(that) {
        var val = that.id;
          if (val == "add"){
             document.getElementById("operator").value = "+";
            } else if (val == "subtract"){
             document.getElementById("operator").value = "-";
            } else if (val == "multiply"){
             document.getElementById("operator").value = "*";
            } else if (val == "divide"){
             document.getElementById("operator").value = "/"; 
            }
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

You were on the right track, your `for` loop looped through each of the selectors, so all you would see was the `/` since that was the last one.  Like @ScottMarucs said, you were also missing a `}`.

Comment: Don't use inline HTML event handlers. See my answer for a list of reasons why.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Agreed, I didn't think about changing it until after I saw your answer.  Just went with what the OP had.

Comment: Also, if you are going to pass a value to `displayOptr`, why not just pass the actual operator that needs to be displayed? Then you can completely get rid of the `if` statement and the function will just be one line of code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah... that would make a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you are missing a closing curly brace for your `if` statement and that is causing an error that is preventing your code from running.

After fixing that, your code loops through your array and upon each iteration, it places one of the symbols into the textbox. But, on the next iteration, it just replaces that symbol. When the code is done, you would always have the `/` in the textbox.

Instead, just pass the symbol you want displayed into the function.

Also, don't set up event handlers as HTML attributes (onclick, onmouseover, etc.) as this old syntax creates "spaghetti code", is hard to read, doesn't scale well, creates implicit global wrapper functions that alter the `this` binding and doesn't follow W3C Standards for Event registration.  Do your event binding in JavaScript with `addEventListener()` instead.

Here's a working version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <div class="leftDiv">
       <div id="colorblock">
        <div id = "add" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr()">ADD</div>
        <div id = "subtract" class = "blocks">SUBTRACT</div>
        <div id = "multiply" class = "blocks">MULTIPLY</div>
        <div id = "divide" class = "blocks">DIVIDE</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    <input type = "text" size="1" id = "operator">
    
    
    <script>
    
    // Get references to the elements you'll need:
    var a = document.getElementById("add");
    var s = document.getElementById("subtract");
    var m = document.getElementById("multiply");
    var d = document.getElementById("divide"); 
    var output = document.getElementById("operator");
    
    // Set up click event handlers that each call the same function but pass it 
    // a different value.
    a.addEventListener("click", function(){ displayOptr("+") });
    s.addEventListener("click", function(){ displayOptr("-") });
    m.addEventListener("click", function(){ displayOptr("*") });
    d.addEventListener("click", function(){ displayOptr("/") });    
    
    function displayOptr(input) {
      // Just take the input and display in the textbox
      output.value = input;       
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't keep it that complicated .. see my answer for an alternative approach with a clean code :)

Comment: @noa-dev There's nothing complicated about this solution. I think you are confusing compact and complicated. Your solution is nice and it is compact, but for a newbie, it is more complicated than my solution.

Comment: This is so complicated. He already told that he is a beginner in js

Comment: @Nimish What exactly is complicated?  There is no loop, no array and no `if` statement. The code uses standards and is exactly the kind of thing that a new JavaScript developer would be learning (getting DOM references, setting up event handlers, updating UI elements).

Comment: Beginner use if and loops only. I am not saying that your answer is wrong but it might be too complicated for him to understand but not for others who knows js very well.

Comment: @Nimish I have been teaching JavaScript (and a host of other programming languages) for over 20 years. Trust me when I tell you that getting a DOM reference, setting up an event handler and updating a UI element is all stuff covered on day 1 of Introduction to JavaScript. Additionally, those 3 concepts are far simpler than `if` logic, array storage and loops.

Comment: i added comments into my solution - the operations should be pretty clear :)

Comment: @noa-dev It's certainly a good solution. I'm just saying that comparatively, understanding that `e` is a reference that is automatically passed to the event handling function (which you didn't explain and so could leave the OP wondering where the value for `e` comes from) and that `target` is a reference to the object that triggered the event and that all the buttons can be wired up to events in a loop is more complex than my solution.

Comment: I understand your POV :-D I also support the way of keeping it as beginner friendly as possible. But I do also like the idea of teaching some new approach if something can be done smoother. While explaining how the approach works :-)

Comment: @noa-dev Agreed. But, you've got to remember to cover everything. Without explaining that event handling functions are automatically passed an argument that references the event object itself and that objects can have properties that store references to other objects (`target`), that code (which to you and I is simple) would be very confusing to a beginner.

Comment: True true :) - If you want to add some necessary comments feel free to edit my answer so we have the best from both worlds :-).

Answer (score 1):

Since the methods loops 4 times it will always display `/` . Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="leftDiv">
      <div id="colorblock">
        <div id = "add" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr('+')">ADD</div>
        <div id = "subtract" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr('-')">SUBTRACT</div>
        <div id = "multiply" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr('*')">MULTIPLY</div>
        <div id = "divide" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr('/')">DIVIDE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type = "text" size="1" id = "operator">
    <script>
      function displayOptr(symbol) {
          document.getElementById("operator").value = symbol;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use inline HTML event handlers. See my answer below for why.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for detailed description

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that you are overcomplicating things.

I would suggest you to alter your code to look like the following:

```
<div class="leftDiv">
            <div id="colorblock">
                <div data-operator="+" class="blocks">ADD</div>
                <div data-operator="-" class="blocks">SUBTRACT</div>
                <div data-operator="*" class="blocks">MULTIPLY</div>
                <div data-operator="/" class="blocks">DIVIDE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
<input type="text" size="1" id ="operator" placeholder="" />
```

Note, that the `data-operator` attribute on the `div`s is being used in the following script:

```
var operatorInput = document.getElementById("operator") // your input field
var buttonList = document.querySelectorAll('.blocks') // Stores all elements with the blocks class in an array

for(var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++){ // loops through all selected elements
    buttonList[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){ // attaches a function to each element
        operatorInput.value = e.target.getAttribute("data-operator") // sets the value of the input field according to the elements data-operator value
  })
}
```

This way you can select all of your buttons programmatically and loop through them to attach them with an event-listener which fires a function when being clicked.

When one of your buttons is being clicked the function emits an event (which is represented as `e` in the code), which refers to the pressed button. The pressed button, which is being represented by the event.target contains the data-operator attribute which you can use to display your desired symbol in the input field.

If you have further questions feel free to ask.

Here is a working fiddle example of that code https://jsfiddle.net/66gu0zur/

Comment: Ah, much better than my answer.

Comment: Glad you like it!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this also. Same code just minor changes

```js
function displayOptr(i) {
    var optrArr =["+","-","*","/"];
    if (i==0){
        document.getElementById("operator").value = "+";
     } else if (i==1){
        document.getElementById("operator").value = "-";
     } else if (i==2){
        document.getElementById("operator").value = "*";
     } else if (i==3){
        document.getElementById("operator").value = "/";    
     }                
}
```

```html
<div class="leftDiv">
    <div id="colorblock">
        <div id = "add" class = "blocks" onclick="displayOptr(0)">ADD</div>
      <div id = "subtract" onclick="displayOptr(1)" class = "blocks">SUBTRACT</div>
      <div id = "multiply" onclick="displayOptr(2)" class = "blocks">MULTIPLY</div>
      <div id = "divide" onclick="displayOptr(3)" class = "blocks">DIVIDE</div>
    </div>
</div>
    <input type = "text" size="1" id = "operator">
```

Comment: Don't use inline HTML event handlers. See my answer for a list of reasons why. Also, if you are going to pass `displayOptr` a value, why not just pass it the actual operator it needs to display? Then you don't need an `if` statement at all.